# Confirm statement w/ if else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a page where a confirm box pops up 10 seconds after the user enters the page. It says "Do you want to leave this page?" If the user clicks OK, it will teleport the user to Google. If the user clicks Cancel, an alert will pop up saying "OK. You can stay." This is just an exercise.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Something.</h1>
<ul>
<li>Info...</li>
<li>More...</li>
<li>Yet More...</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="confirm.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function stayonPage(){
var is_sure = window.confirm("Do you want to leave this page?");
}
var waittime = window.setTimeout("stayonPage()",10000);

if(is_sure=false;)
{window.alert("OK. You can stay.");}
else
{window.location="http://www.google.com";}
```

So far, the web page shows for a second and then goes to Google without the confirm box showing.

Comment: Well, you wait before asking but not before checking the answer and redirecting!!! Put your redirection code in the `stayonPage` function as well.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the script continues its execution.

The `setTimeout` will pop the question after 10 seconds because you set this as the callback function after ten seconds.
BUT - the script continues in the meantime, finds that the `is_sure` variable is undefined, so goes to the `else` statement.

You might put the `if` statement inside the `stayonPage` function that way this block will execute when the function does, after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your redirection if/else block *inside* the `stayonPage` function, as well as use the comparation operator instead of assignment:

```
function stayonPage(){
    var is_sure = window.confirm("Do you want to leave this page?");
    if(is_sure == false) // here you need to use == instead of = and no semi-colon
        {window.alert("OK. You can stay.");}
    else
        {window.location="http://www.google.com";}
}
var waittime = window.setTimeout("stayonPage()",10000);
```

An optimized version of the whole thing would look like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if (!confirm("Do you want to leave this page?"))
        alert("OK. You can stay.");
    else
        window.location="http://www.google.com";
}, 10000);
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/un52w63c/ (note, redirection doesn't work on jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues:

- You're not waiting to test the answer
- You're assigning `is_sure` instead of comparing it

```js
function stayonPage(){
var is_sure = window.confirm("Do you want to leave this page?");
// move it inside the function
if(is_sure==false) // compare, don't assign
{window.alert("OK. You can stay.");}
else
{window.location="http://www.google.com";}
}
setTimeout(stayonPage, 10000);
// don't need to keep a reference, and don't need to use window
// we can just reference the function instead of using implicit eval
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function stayonPage(){
   var is_sure = window.confirm("Do you want to leave this page?"); 

/* is_sure is scoped inside this function it is not a global and
can not be used from a different global function */

/* is_sure=false sets is_sure to false and always returns false and
because it is already a true or false so no condition operation is required */

   if(is_sure) 
     {window.location="http://www.google.com";
   }
   else
     {window.alert("OK. You can stay.");
   }
}



var waittime = window.setTimeout("stayonPage()",10000);
/* 
I assume this will be replace by something more logical,
It will ask if you are sure you wanted to leave without the user
indicating he wanted to leave. 
*/
```